# adding applications onto the widgets list present in home screen

Tags: android, xml

Hie all ,

I am trying to create an simple application and i want that application to show in the widgets  list, i.e on long press on the idle home screen it pops up a spinner for us , you can see it in the below figure, [image]

in that you can see item called widgets which list some set of the applications, even you can see that in the next diagram.[image]. My requirement is that i want my application to be listed there rather showing the general applications list.

thanks
datta

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create a widget application

see these tutorials
http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidWidgets/article.html